# Is amd r7 360 supported by the amdgpu drivers?

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I am unable to confirm if the r7 360 is supported by the amdgpu driver on Ubuntu 20.04. On the ubuntu wiki ot states R7, but not explicit model numbers. Some r7 are cgn 1st gen and others are cgn second gen.

Comment: *Shopping or Hardware Recommendations* are listed as off-topic for this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Ubuntu Forums allows hardware questions.

Comment: Ok. But the its not a shopping or hardware recommendation question. That was just contextual info.

Comment: If it is not a shopping recommendation that means you already own one. so why do you not tell us if it works but booting that system with a live session?

Comment: Correct I do own one. But I am currently on Windows 10, and due to severe bandwidth limitations when I am located, do not want to download an iso unless I can figure out the answer to my question definiteively.

Answer (score -1):

**Proprietary**

Here is a list specifically with the R7 360 proprietary drivers:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/amd-radeon-r7-series/amd-radeon-r7-300-series/amd-radeon-r7-360

Seeing that the support is there only for 12.04.4 LTS and 14.04.2, I would guess that it's the fglrx Catalyst driver, which is not compatible with modern-day versions of the Xorg Server.

**amdgpu-pro**

AMD official info about the amdgpu-pro driver:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-amdgpupro

I see these in the table:

```
AMD Radeon™ R7 240/250/250X/260/260X/350

AMD Radeon™ R9 360 Graphics
```

But I don't see R7 360

[image: amdgpu-pro driver compatibility chart]

**Open source radeon**

Relying on the open source radeon driver, in my personal experience, is like a box of chocolate; you never know how good support you are getting out of it.

All I can tell from personal experience, that with the `AMD FirePro W5130M` unfortunately it seems to be useless. Programs crash to an extent that needs reboot, or don't even start with the radeon driver.

But trying out is for free. Maybe it goes better for you.